# Obtener hora actual de un País específico Android

Tags: android, android-studio, datetime, timestamp

les explicó estoy usando un CountDown y necesito que ese tiempo acabe por igual en todos los dispositivos, ya sea que esté en China o en Panama.

Lo único que se le ha ocurrido es usar una hora estándar aparte de la hora o zona horaria del telefono, una hora que no pueda ser manipulada por el usuario, que si el usuario cambia la hora de su celular, el tiempo siga avanzando perfectamente, o si cambia su zona horaria no afecte esa hora adicional.

he usado TimeZone y agregado una Zona específica pero al cambiar la hora del dispositivo se cambia esa hora.

Lo que deseo es que me orienten como puedo lograr ello. Ya sea a través de una librería o también puediera ser tomando la hora del servidor, estoy usando cloud Firestone firebase que es otra opción que se me ha ocurrido

Necesito que me orienten para seguir avanzando, de antemano gracias a todos los que me ayuden, exitos.

El siguiente codigo te trae la fecha de un pais en especifico, pero si cambias la hora del dispositivo o la zona horaria del mismo, la misma cambia, y lo que deseo es que el usuario cambie su hora, o la zona horario de su movil, se mantenga la hora exacta

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"); 
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(tz); 
String mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
String mMinute c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Otro ejemplo, para que quede mas claro lo que deseo, si en twitter tu creas una encuesta, esta termina en las próximas 24 horas, ya sea que votes de la China, de Portugal o Panamá, la encuesta terminara en 24 horas exacto, si cambias la hora del teléfono o tu zona horario, igual la encuesta termina en 24 horas, por eso necesito obtener una hora, que no pueda  ser manipulada por el usuario al cambiar su hora o zona horario del teléfono...

Comment: Publica el codigo relevante de lo que mas intentando. Y una pregunta. Cuando dices "que ese tiempoacabe por igual a todos" te refieres a que estas desarrollando un temporizador? O es una aplicacion para notificacion segun la hora? Puedes aclarar que tipo de aplicacion estas desarrollando?

Comment: Hola Einer, uso un CountDown, que es una cuenta regresiva, quiero que en todos los dispositivos termine ese countDown termine en al mismo tiempo. Todo lo que he utilizado ha Sido inservible, así que lo que quiero es una nueva orientación, alguna idea de cómo lograrlo y trabajar desde allí, solo necesito obtener una fecha que no pueda ser manipulada por el cliente, con eso ya realizó todo lo que deseo

Comment: Has intentado con UTC?

Comment: Einer, edite la descripción de la pregunta, agregue código usado para que lo leas, con UTC no he intentado, voy a ponerme en ello a ver que logro y te escribo

Comment: Sabes, ahora que lo pienso, hacer un contador y tener en cuentas las zonas horarias podria ser un dolor de cabeza. Porque no manejas el vencimiento desde el servidor? Asi no tendras que preocuparte por la zona horaria para mostrar el contador.

Comment: Fijate he inntentado obtener justamente la  fecha desde el servidor cloud firebase que es donde tengo la bese de dato, pero ha sido otro rollo, tuve que instalar FUNCTIONS de firebase, para poder obtener ese fecha, Eso porque lo lei por allí que era la unica manera de hacerlo, pero me devuelve un Objetc, de paso vacio, porque el System.out me imprime {},así que quede allí trabado, si tu tienes algún código que pueda obtener ello y utilizarlo a ver, te lo agradecería

Comment: @aAaDesigner Debes definir la zona horaria de esa forma obtendrás el valor correcto, agregué respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he podido lograr mi objetivo, lamentablemente  todas las ayudas recibidas no me sirvieron, aunque realizaban el trabajo, al cambiar la hora del dispositivo o la zona horario del dispositivo, se terminaba cambiando la hora, y así no me servia.

Lo he logrando utilizando la librería: [SNTPClient android](https://github.com/aslamanver/sntp-client-android)

Es una libreria super facil de utilizar, y simplemente colocando el codigo indicado, obtienes la fecha en formato string

```
SNTPClient.getDate(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Colombo"), new SNTPClient.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeReceived(String rawDate) {
        // rawDate -> 2019-11-05T17:51:01+0530
        Log.e(SNTPClient.TAG, rawDate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception ex) {
        Log.e(SNTPClient.TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Puedes colocarle la zona horaria del pais que desees y te trae la hora exacta, es independiente del telefono ya que trae la hora desde time.google.com asi que si el  usuario cambia la hora o zona horaria del telefono, siempre obtendrás la hora del país que le  indiques sin importar la hora que tenga el telefono

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener la Hora actual puedes realizarlo de esta forma definiendo la [zona horaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), por ejemplo para tu país podrías usar "America/Caracas":

```
    TimeZone myTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Caracas");
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(myTimeZone);
    String dateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
    System.out.println("Venezuela: " + dateTime);
```

Otros ejemplos por ejemplo Rumania ("Europe/Bucharest"):

```
    TimeZone myTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Bucharest");
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(myTimeZone);
    String dateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
    System.out.println("Rumania: " + dateTime);
```

y México ("America/Mexico_City"):

```
    TimeZone myTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Mexico_City");
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(myTimeZone);
    String dateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
    System.out.println("Mexico City: " + dateTime);
```

Esta es una comparación de la fecha obtenida mediante el método sugerido, como podrás ver se obtiene correctamente la hora e incluso la fecha:

```
Date Venezuela: 2020-08-20 17:40:34
Date Rumania: 2020-08-21 00:40:34
Date Mexico City: 2020-08-20 16:40:34
```

Puedes ver una lista de todos los valores posibles de las [zonas horarias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) en :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

---

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar algo como:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();  
String gmt1=TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz.getID())
      .getDisplayName(false,TimeZone.SHORT);  
String gmt2=TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz.getID())
      .getDisplayName(false,TimeZone.LONG); 
Log.d("Tag","TimeZone : "+gmt1+"\t"+gmt2);
//gmt1 y gmt2 tienen los formatos que debes usar en el siguiente espacio de codigo
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone('Aqui tienes que utilizar el dato obtenido'); 
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(tz); 
String mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
String mMinute c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

no tengo android studio code para verificar este script.

Comment: Hola francisco, ya voy a probar tu codigo y te escribo, gracias

Comment: Hola Francisco, si esto lo tomaste de algún lugar, es importante dar crédito respectivo a el autor: https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/android/como-obtener-el-desplazamiento-de-la-zona-horaria-en-gmt-como-gmt-7-00-desde-el-dispositivo-android/1071226589/

Comment: @Elenasys en realidad lo tome de un código muy viejo que tenia; y como no se si ha cambiado algo en android o android studio respecto al objeto `TimeZone` y no poder hacer una prueba previa no ya que no tengo el software, le dije que procediera con cautela.